# Label Text Changed Event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

In my page if the text of a Label has been Changed I need to fire some function using JQuery as `.Change()` is restricted to only `<input> and <select>` I use a function like

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").on('labelchanged', function () {
       alert('changed!');          
    }
    });
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").trigger('labelchanged')
```

but the above function is not triggered when the text of the label has been changed kindly anyone point me what could be I am missing in the above function

**Edit:** The label's text will be changed during runtime only when some message occurs or some exception is been thrown it is ued to display that exception

My aspx Code where the label text will be changed

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
       //submit code//
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
       lblMsg.Text=ex.Message();
     }
}
```

Comment: use jsfiddle for show your code ... and add your html codes into that

Comment: it works, http://jsbin.com/gobahiza/1/edit, not sure about your question, you created custom event and triggered it manually but it didn't work? or built-in change event from jquery doesn't work?

Comment: @YuliamChandra it is working in the Fiddle link you had given but when I change the code like above its not working and for your info the label is used display the validation message or exception message so the text will change only when there is any valiadtion message occurs or exception occurs during runtime.

Comment: @Rajesh you are using asp.net with master page? you need to post more code (aspx code) and more javascript code that is related to the change event you were talking about..

Comment: @YuliamChandra Yes I am using asp.net with master page and I also posted the Button click aspx code where the Labels button text will be changed

Comment: @Rajesh please put more code how you call $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").trigger('labelchanged'), is it from something like $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").on("change", function(){});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").on('labelchanged', function () {
       alert('changed!');          
});

$("#btn_change").on('click', function(){
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").html('New Label Text').trigger('labelchanged');
    });

$(window).on('keypress', function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13')
        $("#btn_change").trigger('click');
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nazmoonnoor/nmKaG/2/)

Comment: It is Working only when we press the button i.e click the button if we press the Enter key in the key board for click of the same button and the text of the label has been changed this event doesn't get fired unless we focus on the button using mouse pointer or using tab key and press enter

Comment: triggering your button on enter key press don't work?

Comment: @Rajesh, changed my answer and demo. check now.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions/answer similar to your problem right here on stackoverflow.

I don't think you can just trigger any user-defined event in jquery like that. The workaround is using promise like this:

```
$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lblMsg").html("Duplicate record can't be saved.").promise().done(function(){
    alert('changed!');  
});
```